# IOnic Storage forEach returns nor all entries

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ionic-framework

I'm using the ionic storage.
In the storage I have 41 entries. Now I would like to read them all into an array. Furthermore, I'd like to filter some out.
My code is the following:

```
async getEntries() {
 this.trackingEntries = [];
 let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.storage.forEach((value, key, index) => {
    if (key != "Options0" && key != "Options1" && key != "Options2" && key != "Options3" && key != "welcome" && key != "LockedOptions") {
      this.trackingEntries.push(value);
      console.log(index, value)
    }
  }).then(() => {
    console.log(this.trackingEntries)
    resolve(this.trackingEntries.length);
  });
});
return promise;
}
```

My problem is, that the function returns different values. Sometimes 33, sometimes 38 and so on.
Can somebody help me to fix this?

Comment: What does the `this.storage` variable contain, is the async operation really necessary ?

Comment: I‘m using it like in the docs: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage